# How to extract a number value from a string containing CSS rules

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Given a string with a format similar to this:

```
"color: blue; padding: 10px 0; transition: all 1.5s;"
```

I would like to extract the number `1.5` (or whatever it is the number there).
I though that I could:

1) Split the string at the `";"`;

2) for each substring see if it contains `"transition"`;

3) if it does, then extract the number.

The closest I could get was:

```
String.split("string", ";") |> Enum.map(fn(x) -> if Regex.match?(~r/transition:/, x) do
    String.replace(x, "transition: all ", "") end
    end
```

This isn't working and also by using `String.replace` I get two problems with this part: `transition: all 1.5s`:

1) I can't clean the trailing `s`;

2) I can have other text instead of just `all`;

So, how to do this work while solving these latter issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Regex.scan/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3) and pattern matching result come to the rescue:

```
iex(1)> [[_, value]] = ~r{transition:.*?([\d.])s.*?;} 
          |> Regex.scan("color: blue; padding: 10px 0; transition: all 1.5s;")
#⇒ [["transition: all 1.5s;", "1.5"]]
iex(2)> value
#⇒"1.5"
```

If you expect that string might or might not have a match:

```
case ~r{transition:.*?([\d.])s.*?;} 
     |> Regex.scan("color: blue; padding: 10px 0; transition: all 1.5s;") do
  [[_, value]] -> value |> String.to_float
  _ -> IO.puts "Sorry, no match"
end
#⇒ 1.5
```

Comment: Great! I just took a few minutes to go over it and understand it fully. That's really powerful, I think. Now you reduced the problem to mastering Regexs. Nevertheless, I'm interested in capturing the time units (`1.5`, `2000`, `5`,...), not just the `5 of 1.5`. Is it simple to change the Regex to achieve that? Thank you mudasobwa.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for that. Updated.